# How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement Oauth Security in Spring MVC.

this is my java based configuration :

public class HelloWorldConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

```
 public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

 @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/peoplecheck");
        return dataSource;
    }
 @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver =
                        new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

}

THis is my pom :

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
    <javax.validation.version>1.1.0.Final</javax.validation.version>
    <springsecurity.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <springsecurityoauth2.version>2.0.10.RELEASE</springsecurityoauth2.version>
    <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.1</version>
    </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security OAuth2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurityoauth2.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I am using websphere application server. Whenever i try to run the application i get this exception and very confused what is missing.
if i go with only java based it works fine, while i need to implement in xml based or both as i cant change the entire project.

```
00000056 DispatcherSer E org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean Context initialization failed
                                 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterComparator.<init>(FilterComparator.java:74)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.<init>(HttpSecurity.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:290)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91437efb.init(<generated>)
```

Comment: You can find excellent solutions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy the same thing runs without xml based configuration... i am not able to understand "Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter"

Comment: Did you read the link I shared?

Answer (score 3):

`spring-security 4.1.1.RELEASE` uses `spring-framework version 4.3.1.RELEASE`. Can you try updating your spring version?

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom

Answer (score 1):

It seems your CorsFilter is not implemented properly. You should try this filter

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOG.info("Adding CORS Headers ........................");        
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
         res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else { 
         chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }        
    }
}
```

You can refer to the working example [Cross Origin Request Blocked](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/cross-origin-request-blocked-spring-mvc-restful-angularjs.html) 
Hope this help.